# Breakpoint on Entry for Every Method in JDB

Tags: java, debugging, jdb

Is it possible to make JDB pause upon entry into any method? I can manually specify which methods to stop at by using the `stop in` command, but I would like to apply the breakpoint to all methods that are executed.

Comment: how about using some IDE? It gives you that feature in quick win

Comment: @PiotrKorlaga I'm trying to make an automated script that tracks method calls step by step, so sadly using an IDE isn't an option.

Comment: If an IDE can do it, there must be a way for me to do it as well, right?

Comment: I believe so, but I'm afraid I cannot help with that.

Comment: What do you mean by every method / any method? Methods which are in your own packages? With AOP, I think, you can try something with around aspect and its joint-point, just put a breakpoint on proceed method.